# Jasmine Test - Unknown provider $sceProvider

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write a jasmine test for my filter.
Here is my filter:

```
angular.module('CPSCore.Filters').filter('TextToHtmlSafe', ['$sce', function     ($sce)
{
return function (text)
{
        if (!text)
            return text;

        var htmlText = text.replace(/\<br \/\>/g, '\n');
        htmlText = htmlText.replace(/\<br\/\>/g, '\n');
        htmlText = htmlText.replace(/\<br\>/g, '\n');
        htmlText = htmlText.replace(/\</g, '< ');
        htmlText = htmlText.replace(/\&/g, '& ');
        htmlText = htmlText.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlText);

   };
 }]);
```

here is my jasmine test:

```
describe('CPSCore.Filters', function() {

var TextToHtmlSafeFilter, $sce;

beforeEach(module('CPSCore.Filters'));
beforeEach(inject(function (_$sce_, $filter) {
    $sce = _$sce_;
    TextToHtmlSafeFilter = $filter('TextToHtmlSafe');
}));



it('should replace \n with <br />', function () {
    expect($sce.getTrustedHtml(TextToHtmlSafeFilter('testing\n'))).toEqual('testing<br />');       

});



});
```

I am receiving this error in Karma when running the test:

Error: Unknown provider: $sceProvider <- $sce

can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create the module correctly? Did you define `angular.module('CPSCore.Filters', [] )` (with brackets) in your test?

Comment: module works fine. test fails, all the code is above I have not omitted anything

Answer (score 0):

Obviously module doesn't work fine. You have to **create** the module with an empty dependency list!

```
var app = angular.module('CPSCore.Filters', []);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QsbYLNhROkc4OpWQ8xH1?p=preview)

Comment: Your attitude to this post is not really welcomed. I advised that my module works fine which it does, my module creation and declaration is done outside the scope of the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem which was actually in my karma.config file. I forgot to add the new angular version into the config file.